# Unable to create a new app on foursquare

Tags: foursquare

I am trying to create an app on foursquare. I do fill all the required fields. By submitting the app form will result in `400 bad request` with no message in the browser.

However the Response looks like this:

```
{"meta":{"code":400,"errorType":"param_error","errorDetail":"Value  is invalid for pushVersion"},"response":{}}
```

Can it be a bug on their side, or am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: First of all Let's look at it from a normal user perceptive, You just fill in required field https://foursquare.com/developers/register and expect either error or success message, which I don't see in my case. The Post is sending an empty value for pushVersion. I am guessing it might be a bug on foursquare.

Comment: Heyo, just updating for the record that these errors should be fixed by now. Sorry for the inconvenience this caused! As always, follow [@foursquareAPI](https://twitter.com/foursquareAPI) for constant updates from us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was also just getting this error.... The pushVersion being posted to /v2/apps/create is blank and there is no visible user input for the field. The field is in the markup though so if you use Chrome dev tools or firebug you can find the version input's div wrapper and remove the style="display: none;", then fill in the field. I entered "20130115" and chose that I didn't want pushes and the app was created successfully.

Comment: Yeah really sorry about this guys! We've been making some changes to this part of the developer site recently which has unfortunately surfaced some bugs. If this little trick seems to work now, let's stick with that. We'll update you guys when there's more on this.